# how can i display List<object> contain in jsp

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am unable to display data from controller to JSP-page in Spring MVC. I am new to Spring.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/employee"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAllemployee(ModelMap model){
        List<Memployee> Memployee=empService.getAllEmployee();
        model.addAttribute("Memployee", Memployee);
        return "list-emp";
    }
```

And this is my JSP-page:

```
<c:forEach items="${Memployee}" var="emp">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">${emp.id}</th>
      <td>${emp.first_name}</td>
      <td>${emp.last_name}</td>
      <td>${emp.username}</td>
      <td><a href="">Edit</a> || <a href="">View</a> || <a href="">Delete</a> || <a href="">Add</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually get the list (non-empty) from service?

Comment: yes I get the list of data in object